# Column 'tax_id' cannot be NOT NULL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am working in a project where a table has a foreign key called `tax_id,` the problem is that in some point another migration was created to change the `tax_id` to nullable.

```
Schema::table('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedInteger('tax_id')->nullable()->change();
});
```

I realize this after I wrote other migrations and tried to run them, it throws `Column 'tax_id' cannot be NOT NULL,` it seems that in the "project" that migration was run, so I can't just delete the file, how can I run my migrations without the error? I have tried to remove the foreign key, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're working with MySQL InnoDB because you did not specify the database type/engine.

You could try different approaches:

1) If yuo're in hurry, disable foreign keys, do the update, enable the foreign key. You should then correct the problem of course.

2) Add set tax_id to '' where tax_id is null and then do the migration

3) Document yourself about the database engine and implement a correct solution

Giacomo